# about parameterized query

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, informix, parameterized-query

Q:

Please , i want to ask ,how to perform a query(select statement) using a parametrized query in Informix database ,with a simple example.
thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

i use

`IfxConnection` and `IfxCommand`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB

This is just one connection string sample for the wrapping OleDbConnection class that calls the underlying OLEDB provider. See respective OLE DB provider for more connection strings to use with this class.

```
Provider=Ifxoledbc;Data Source=dbName@serverName;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

 public void CreateMyOleDbCommand(OleDbConnection connection,
    string queryString, OleDbParameter[] parameters) 
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
    command.CommandText = 
        "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers WHERE Country = ? AND City = ?";
    command.Parameters.Add(parameters);

    for (int j=0; j<parameters.Length; j++)
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(parameters[j]) ;
    }

    string message = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < command.Parameters.Count; i++) 
    {
        message += command.Parameters[i].ToString() + "\n";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: thanks a lot but , i face many problems when i use `IfxConnection`,`IfxCommand`, if u can clarify the same example with these classes instead

Comment: this is generic sql ole db command of .net framework. You can refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Only thing that id different in oledbcommand with other command is that you need to pass ? as parameter instead we use @param in other. Also if you need some generic approach. You can look into DbFactoryProvider class in MSDN